# Getting list of users from our facebook connect application

Tags: facebook

I have a website that uses facebook connect to allow users to login to the site's login system.  If I want to verify that the facebook user id's captured by our database match those who are authorized by facebook to our application by facebook and vice-versa, how would I do that?

For example, if I log in the facebook developer application and it tells me that we have 7 users (I assume this means 7 people who have "connected" to our application), where would I find a list of those 7 users.

I assume their facebook user id's are public information, yet I would like a way to obtain them in a list pertaining to our application.

I assume that this is common for the purposes of database maintenance (and in my case just to verify that everything is working properly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me based on the dev console that you can't get a list like this. The best you can do is get `friend.getAppUsers()` which gives you a list of your *friends* that have the app installed. Bummer; I actually really need this too for an application I'm working on. I guess just use the post-authorize, deauthorize callback urls to manage the list of users on your end.

Answer (score 1):

I missed first lot of application users too.

Then I start to add username and ID to database as soon as they visit the first page of application after authorizing the application.

Now anybody new comes to my application they are added to 'appusers' table

Comment: check if 'fbid' field is already there before adding new entry, that way you do not keep adding same user for each time they visit the application. For next visit, if I find their ID in 'appusers' database, I just update the database with 'logindate' and 'logintime' to know their last login

Comment: Thanks for answering. This question is over two years old, but I appreciate the answer anyway. Hopefully will be helpful for someone on here.